# How to generate calendar of movable feasts?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

There is a table: feasts with dates stored in smallint fields (not elegant way, I know..).
It looks like that:

```
id - serial, PK
day - smallint NOT NULL,
month - smallint NOT NULL,
year - smallint
```

It seems very simple - if there is a record for some date, there is also some kind of feast on that date.

There is "only" one thing that makes the whole idea complicated... Field 'year' is nullable. If 'year' is null, that means there is movable feast on that day - independent from year. (Of course I can create one field for date, and some boolean flag 'is_movable', but it wouldn't change anything in my problem).

I want to create procedure to list all feasts for specified range of dates.

```
get_all_feasts(date_from date, date_to date)
```

..which returns table: id, date, is_movable.

For example, for data:

```
id / day / month / year
1 / 12 / 05 / 2013
2 / 15 / 05 / 2013
3 / 16 / 02 / 2012
4 / 25 / 12 / NULL
5 / 26 / 12 / NULL
6 / 2 / 04 / 2014
```

..function call: get_all_feasts('2012-03-01'::date, '2014-05-01'::date)
should return:

```
id / date
4 / 2012-12-25
5 / 2012-12-26
1 / 2013-05-12
2 / 2013-05-15
4 / 2013-12-25
5 / 2013-12-26
6 / 2014-04-02
```

There is no problem with selecting feasts with year, month and day specified.

But how to generate feast dates for movable feasts in specific range?

I use PostgreSQL v. 9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use WITH RECURSIVE queries - [Reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html)

try this -

```
WITH RECURSIVE year_table(n) AS (
    SELECT 1000
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM year_table
)
SELECT Id, To_Date(DAY || ' ' || MONTH || ' ' || YEAR, 'DD MM YYYY')
  FROM Feasts
 WHERE To_Date(DAY || ' ' || MONTH || ' ' || YEAR, 'DD MM YYYY') >=
       Date_From
   AND To_Date(DAY || ' ' || MONTH || ' ' || YEAR, 'DD MM YYYY') <= Date_To
   AND YEAR IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Feasts.Id,
       To_Date(DAY || ' ' || MONTH || ' ' || Year_Table.n, 'DD MM YYYY')
  FROM Feasts, Year_Table
 WHERE n >= To_Char(Date_From, 'YYYY')
   AND n <= To_Char(Date_To, 'YYYY')
   AND Feasts.YEAR IS NULL;
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but with your help I managed to solve the problem, so I accept the answer. :)

Comment: @cathulhu.. what was the problem you were facing. Please update me also so that I will also keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    id, (coalesce(year, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())) || '-' || month || '-' || day) as date
FROM
    feasts
WHERE 
    (coalesce(year, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())) || '-' || month || '-' || day)::date >= date_from
    AND (coalesce(year, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())) || '-' || month || '-' || day)::date <= date_to
ORDER BY
    (coalesce(year, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())) || '-' || month || '-' || day)::date, id;
```